# Store files in directory into array, then loop through that array

Tags: arrays, file, shell, loops, directory

I have a folder called 'sql' that contains .sql files. I want to write a script that searches for all .sql files, puts the filename into an array, and then kicks off each file.

ie:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Options
 DBHOST=MySQL-hostname
 DBNAME=MySQL-database
 DBUSER=MySQL-username
 DBPASS=MySQL-password

 # Find .sql Files
 ???

 # Create MySQL Tables
 for i in "${TBNAME[@]}"; do
   mysql -h "$DBHOST" -u "$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASS" "$DBNAME" < $TBNAME[$i]
 done
```

How can I search for .sql files within a specified folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for sqlfile in sql/*.sql ; do
    # do things to $sqlfile
done
```

For example you can save the full pathnames in a table by using `echo "$PWD/$sqlfile"`

Comment: Even easier! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Late aswer (after accepted one) but for the record:

```
printf "source %s\n" sql/**/*.sql | mysql --batch
```

for this you need to have in the `~/.bash_profile` line:

```
shopt -s globstar #or put this before the above line
```

How it works:

```
printf "source %s\n" sql/**/*.sql
```

produces lines like

```
source sql/some/file.sql
source sql/other/file2.sql
#and such...
```

recursively for all found *.sql files, and the

```
mysql --batch .... other arguments
```

will read the "source filename" lines - and executes the sql commands in the files, all in one execution, not need start (run) multiple times the `mysql` command...